# Chrome "Launched External Handler" console statement with mailto link

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I've noticed this line in console.log in Chrome recently and it has me thinking that I'm doing something wrong when programmatically launching a `mailto:` link.

The line appears to be invoked from the Chromium source code from the `external_protocol_handler.cc` file at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/browser/external_protocol/external_protocol_handler.cc

And the specific code triggering the console statement is:

```
web_contents->GetMainFrame()->AddMessageToConsole(
      blink::mojom::ConsoleMessageLevel::kInfo,
      "Launched external handler for '" + url.possibly_invalid_spec() + "'.");
```

The function name `url.possibly_invalid_spec()` has me questioning.

All I'm doing is using JavaScript to open a `mailto:` link from a `https://` website (if that has anything to do with it) `window.location.href = 'mailto:me@website.com';`

Anyone heard of this?  Is it new?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at [git blame](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+blame/master/chrome/browser/external_protocol/external_protocol_handler.cc#146), we see that logger was added on June 24, 2020 by Eric Lawrence as part of [the fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/89eb57915ce2ae2c2f06e5474bd3c12b23397540%5E%21/chrome/browser/external_protocol/external_protocol_handler.cc) for bug 1096610 with the following explanation:

> Log external handler invocations to the console.

> Previously, failing to invoke an external protocol handler ('foo://bar')
> would fail silently if the protocol was not registered or if the user
> gesture requirement was not met. This limitation made it difficult for
> web developers to troubleshoot such situations. This CL emits errors to
> the Developer Tools console when the protocol handler is not registered,
> is forbidden, or is temporarily blocked pending a user-gesture.
> Similarly, if an external handler is launched, an informational log
> entry is added.

With that in mind, one can conclude it's ok to have in DevTools console since it's just a notification that a browser is about to try and handle a link with an external protocol other than `http/https` (for example, `mailto`, `ftp`, etc).

Comment: Hi Viacheslav, by saying "...since it's just a notification that a browser is about to try and handle a link with an external protocol...", did you mean that even Chrome said "Launched external handler for..." in the Console, it still not a guarantee that the application will be launched? If so what could be the reason? I have an issue these days to launch our app from Chrome by using the app protocol, e.g. test://xxxx, and Chrome said it is launched, but it DID NOT, nothing happens. It works on some computers while some are not. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Bill, the console message saying "Launched external handler <...and the rest>" might be a bit misleading because actual call to platform_util::OpenExternal at the moment of this writing happens on line 153 whereas the message is logged at line 149.
Without some details (e.g. a platform, an app, a container type, a way of invoking the app, etc) it's hard to identify the root cause.
I'd try to analyze the difference between your development machine and another computer where the app is being successfully launched through a link with a custom protocol.

Comment: The answer to your first question is "yes, it's not a guarantee".
See line 157 with a comment regarding navigation occurred in a new tab.

Comment: Thank you for the timely reply. I do see the log was written before the launch is actually happening, mislead indeed. I'm on Windows 10, the latest Chrome, and I have written a very simple JavaScript to launch my test app, something like `<script language="javascript">window.location.href = 'myapp://login/open?account=xxxx&token=xxx</script>`, the protocol handler was registered to Windows registry correctly, what confused me is that it works for most of our computers but some did not, I'm still working to find out any differences between these PCs. Thank you again ;D